# Creating a user account page in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

I am creating a user account(useraccount.aspx) page in c#. I have to display the account page once the user clicks the submit button in the registration page(userregistration.aspx). I have uploaded the user image to a folder in my application and the image path is saved in my database. Please find below the code in my user registration page for uploading user images.

```
 string filename = Path.GetFileName(fuUploadPhoto.PostedFile.FileName);

        if (fuUploadPhoto.HasFile)
        {
            if (fuUploadPhoto.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpeg")
            {
                fuUploadPhoto.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/PhotoCollection/" + filename));


                try
                {
                    objcon.Open();

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into ImagesPath(ImageName,ImagePath,userName) values(@ImageName,@ImagePath,@userName)", objcon);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageName", filename);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImagePath", "~/PhotoCollection/" + filename);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", txtDesiredUserName.Text.ToString());
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                }
                finally
                {

                    objcon.Close();
                    lblPhoto.Text = "Photo uploaded successfully";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblPhoto.Text = "Uploaded image is not of correct format";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblPhoto.Text = "Please upload an image";
        }
```

Now how can i access this image in useraccount.aspx page? I am stuck up here. Please guide me.

Comment: Explain step by step what your code does and what you want it to do. How do you mean you want to "access" the image?

Answer (score 1):

After the button click for the registration: response.redirect to the viewProfile.aspx (or something). And have an `asp:image`

```
<asp:Image id="Image1" runat="server"
       AlternateText="Image text"
       ImageUrl="images/noImage.jpg"/>
```

in the Page_Load of the viewProfile.aspx get the user from the database and

```
Image1.ImageUrl = YourDataRowFromDb["ImagePath"].ToString();
```

Or isn't it Asp.Net webforms?